# Loading multiple tableviews in a UIView (UIView Controller)

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, ipad

I've been searching all throughout the internet for assistance, however there has been little to no solutions to my issue at hand. My project that im trying to get a gasp on is somewhat unique (UI is not exactly following the typical norms).

Current Development Enviroment:

- xcode 4
- storyboards instead of nibs

Below is a diagram of what i am trying to accomplish -- all within a UIView Controller:

[image]

- UIView is the light grey background
- UITableView 1 - this is a static (or it can be dynamic, thats another challenge) UITableview which will hold different numeric
  values for calculation
- UITableView 2 - this is a UITableview which will hold calculated results every time it is run.
- UIImageView 1 - this is a calculated image example (I have that figured out)

Im sure experienced developers are fully aware of my issue, and or what im about to ask. I understand that a static UITableView is required to be in a tableview controller, but I need to display both the UItableView's at the same time which means it has to be within a UIView.

I can make the interface look the way I need it to through the IB however when trying to compile and build I receive the error that requires the UITableView's to be within a UITableViewController and not a UIView Controller. I have seen many examples using a master-detail layout, but the only stipulation is that this UITableview NEEDS to be displayed 100% of the time when in this view.

So basically, I am asking for direction... but a code example never hurt either! Thank you 100x's over!

-Jonathan

Comment: Is this for the iPhone or iPad? It makes a big difference.

Comment: are you using a UITableViewController? or is it a UIViewController with a UITableView+Delegate+Datasource methods?

Comment: This is for the iPad, sorry for the confusion. The "default" view would be a UIViewController.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UITableViewController` is just a specialized `UIViewController` specially designed to display full screen `UITableView`s. It is (quite) equivalent to use an `UITableViewController` subclass or an `UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>` subclass to manage a tableview.

So even if `UITableViewController` has some more spiecialized behaviors (automatically creates the UITableView if it does not exists, scrolls it automatically to display the keyboard, sets itself as the `delegate` and `dataSource` of the unique `UITableView` it manages, etc), you can use a standard `UIViewController` to manage a `UITableView` and be its `dataSource` to fill it.

That's even a way to manage a tableview that is not taking the full screen (as `UITableViewController` expects its `view` property to directly be the `UITableView` it manages, not a subview of its main view or whatever, and thus expects the `UITableView` to take the whole screen, contrary to using an `UIViewController` that has an `UITableView` as a custom-sized subclass of its `view`)

---

So in your case, you can have an `UIViewController` that has two `IBOutlets`, one for each `tableView`, and that unique `UIViewController` can be the `dataSource` (and `delegate`) of **both** the `UITableViews`. That's not a problem. Just be careful then in your datasource methods to distinguish if you are returning data for the first or the second `UITableView` to feed the correct tables each time.

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView* masterTableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView* detailsTableView;
@end

@implementation MyViewController
@synthesize masterTableView = _masterTableView;
@synthesize detailsTableView = _detailsTableView;

// Proper memory mgmt not shown here:
//  - don't forget to set self.masterTableView and self.detailsTableView to nil in viewDidUnload
// - and to release _masterTableView and _detailsTableView in your dealloc method

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell;
    if (tableView == self.masterTableView)
    {
        static NSString* kMasterCellIdentifier = @"MasterCell";
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kMasterCellIdentifier];
        if (!cell)
        {
          cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithReuseIdentiier:kMasterCellidentifier] autorelease];
          // do some configuration common to all your master cells
        }
        // configure the rest of your cell for each property that is different from one cell to another
    }
    else if (tableView == self.detailsTableView)
    {
        // Do exactly the same principle, but for the cells of your "details" TableView
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: are you sure?
`if (tableView == self.masterTableView)` ??
 `else if (tableView = self.detailsTableView)` ??

Comment: Yup, why? I just compare the `tableView` parameter passed to the datasource method with each of my two tableview to see for which of the two I need to build a cell. What's the problem here? (Note that you don't need to compare these using `isEqual:` here as pointer comparison is sufficient in that case)

Comment: Great, once I return home today I will start to rebuild my classes. I'll be sure to return here to let everyone know how it went!

Comment: That was a great start. My code has basically double after adding in plist support for my new fields etc but you got me off the ground running!