# How to have 2 tableview in one view controller with 1 tableview being dependent to the other

Tags: uitableview, core-data, delegates, xcode6

I'm in the process of creating an app that needs to have 2 TableViews that is linked to core data. The first table View is the Parent tableview wherein the user **needs** to select it before the 2nd table view populates with the associated data. I've been looking at examples and solutions but I came upon an issue with the FetchRequest Controller. how will it know which table to query?

I saw an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466428/loading-multiple-tableviews-in-a-uiview-uiview-controller) but its not that complete. or at least, It did not gave a complete detail as to how to set the 2nd tableview's Delegate and Datasource. well, the delegate is the ViewController but what about the Datasource? how would it know which data to pull from?

I hope you guys can assist with this dilemma or at least, point me to an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a `UIViewController` rather than a `UITableViewController`.  Add two `UITableViews`, either in code or in a storyboard, and create two properties for them - let's say `parentTableView` and `childTableView`.  Make your view controller both the delegate and dataSource for both tableViews.  When you implement the relevant methods, begin by checking the tableView parameter that is passed in the method call, and provide the relevant data:

```
if (tableView == self.parentTableView) {
    // provide data relevant to the parent...

} else { // provide data relevant to the child...

}
```

To provide the data for the tables, you could use one fetched result controller for the parent, and then use the parent - child relationship to derive the data for the child table view (eg. for `numberOfRowsInSection` for the child, you might use `[self.selectedParent.children count]`, and so on).  This will work fine, but you lose the benefits of using a fetched results controller for the child objects: automatic table sections, and automatic updates when new child objects are inserted/updated/deleted.

If you would prefer, you can use two separate fetched result controllers - one for the parent objects, and another for the child objects.  Create a property for each, say `parentFRC` and `childFRC`, and then use the relevant one to provide the data in the tableView delegate methods as above.  For the `childFRC`, you should set a predicate which limits the fetched child objects to those whose parent is the selected parent in the `parentTableView`.  (You will need to reperform the fetch for the `childFRC` when the selected parent changes).

If you use the `NSFetchedResultController` delegate methods to keep track of changes to the data, you should again set your view controller as the delegate for both FRCs, and in your implementation of the relevant methods, check the `fetchedResultController` parameter that is passed in the method call to determine which object has been changed - parent or child - and update the appropriate table.

Comment: you have shed some light to my dilemma! I'll do this ASAP :)